# WSDL2JAVA does not generate setter methods

Tags: java, apache-axis, wsdl2java, ibm-jdk

Has anyone come across this? Basically I switched from the SUN jre to IBM's and compilation fails due to wsdl2java not having compiled the necessary setter methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `wsdl2java` is a Sun JDK tool. If there's something with the same name in the IBM JDK, it may well behave completely differently. These tools are not standard.

Comment: Are you sure? I'd say it's an Axis tool and its qualified name is org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java. Also see http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using jaxb?

Does the generated code have anything like this in it?

```
/**
     * Gets the value of the parameter property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the parameter property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getParameter().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
```

Comment: Not using JAXB. But, still, please share your thought on what might be going wrong.

Comment: Possibly for the same reason as jaxb.  You're only missing setters for lists right?  Or are you missing setters for everything?  Depending on how the xml binding is done, it needs some state somewhere, so you can't just replace it with a new object of your own.

Comment: I'm missing setters for Strings, longs, ints and so on.

Comment: does anyone found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug report on this in the Axis2 issues system, opened after you asked your question. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4968.